Conditionally Rendered Components seem to cause bugs in ios browsers
The more websites I work on the more I'm starting to notice there's something odd about how ios handles components that enter and leave the DOM conditionally.  Some of the issues I run into are

Buttons need to be double tapped in order to trigger whatever action I need them to perform while buttons in the non conditionally rendered parts of the site work perfectly fine with single taps.
Search filters don't work properly as the user types regardless to if I'm using a keyup, keydown or onchange event.
SVG elements don't render properly while rendering perfectly fine in non conditionally rendered parts of the website.  Sometimes they cause the entire site to freeze similar to when there's an infinite loop error but all works fine when I comment them out of the code.

This doesn't seem to be platform specific as I've run into these issues when working on Angular, React and Vue projects in both TypeScript and vanilla Javascript.  I've had access to a mac on a couple occasions and was able to sync a device to it so I could try to debug it but couldn't find any issues and didn't get any errors in the console.  Does anybody know what might be going on under the hood that might be causing problems with elements that render conditionally?
